How to create writable Linux installation device instead of a “iso9660” device?
Let's say I downloaded a bootable ISO of some Linux distribution, because I want to install Linux later.
I can burn that ISO onto my USB flash drive. However the device will keep the iso9660 filesystem, so it won't be writable. I can install Linux, but I cannot do anything else with my USB flash drive.
So, is it possible convert the ISO into a "normal" ext4 filesystem, and still keep the USB stick bootable?

You can always modify the ISO to contain more files prior to burning but what application is used to create the media?

I haven't looked into how it was achieved but found that when openSUSE-Leap-15.5-GNOME-Live-x86_64-Build13.195-Media.iso was copied to a USB stick that Live image on writeable media is preserving state. The openSUSE Leap live ISO has been created in a way which seems to use the unused space on the USB stick to provide persistent storage as some sort of overlayfs.

"I can burn that ISO onto my USB stick" – See this answer for insight.

@Ramhound your question is worth. I used Balena Etcher to burn the DVD. Now I know that other tools (unetbootin, rufus) behave differently.

I found by myself another answer. I hope this can help others. (Using Linux)

I formatted USB flash drive as ext4
I mounted the ISO file as a local disk
I copied all files from ISO to  USB flash drive
I installed grub on the USB key: sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc /dev/sdc


Since you found your own solution, could you post which Linux distribution you are using?

The ISO was for Linux Mint. The linux distribution I used for downloading and creating the USB flash drive was Linux Peppermint (an Ubuntu derivative).

This might be obvious, but I will ask anyway. Will you be installing Linux Mint to legacy BIOS boot or UEFI boot? Also, did you MBR or GPT partition the USB flash drive, then ext4 format /dev/sdc1? Or did you ext4 format /dev/sdc?

USB flash drive is MBR, and I formatted /dev/sdc1 with ext4. I used gparted for this. The command grub-install --target=i386-pc is for BIOS installation, AFAIK.

I did make an attempt to verify your answer. I was able to create a BIOS bootable flash drive Mint installer and install Mint. However, I did need to add the --boot-directory option to the grub-install command.

The Peppermint OS I used was BIOS booting Debian Based. The Linux Mint was the Cinnamon Edition. Both were 64 bit.

iso9660 is not what makes it bootable here – it's the filesystem that CDs/DVDs use, and your firmware would indeed be looking for special ISO9660 header fields if you were booting this image from an actual CD, but those become completely irrelevant when booting from any other type of disk. The USB stick is bootable only because the image was a "hybrid ISO" with a traditional MBR boot sector, and/or EFI system partition, written alongside the ISO9660 data.
So yes, it is possible to e.g. create a regular ext4 filesystem (or even FAT32, as most "live CDs" have the actual Linux rootfs in a SquashFS image anyway), extract the contents of the ISO9660 into it, and install a bootloader into the USB stick's MBR – most such CDs use isolinux, so you'd install the regular syslinux/extlinux onto the USB stick and hopefully it'll pick up the existing syslinux.cfg.
Rufus and similar tools are often capable of extracting the contents of your Linux ISO into a more regular filesystem and making it bootable. (It doesn't always work 100% because such tools rely in part on recognizing the specific contents of a Linux ISO image and adapting them, but it still works most of the time.)

I was thinking Rufus was a solution here just didn’t know what was already being used.

Just tried Rufus and it is a good solution, it has all required properties. Unluckily it works only in Windows, not in Linux.

There are probably several Linux equivalents. I remember Unetbootin used to be a thing (although it was just as likely to break the boot process completely). In the end the process is roughly: "create EFI partition, create root partition, mkfs.ext4, unpack the .iso contents into it, install syslinux or grub as appropriate".

Write an Ubuntu live ISO (installation media) onto a USB-memory.
IF you Boot it once (in "Try Ubuntu" mode),
you will get a "writeable" partition covering the "free" parts of the stick's memory
(i.e. those parts not occupied by the ISO-image).
Sadly this cannot be used for data transfers as e.g. gparted or any OS (besides the one booted from the stick!) does not see 'writeable' for mounting - it is likely "inside" the ISO image.
But this does work:
Before you boot the first time; use any partitioning tool and create at least one second partition
Details from @DavidAnderson 's comment below:
I used the fdisk --wipe never command to create the 4th partition. This command automatically moved the secondary (backup) partition table and header to the end of the flash drive. I used the mkfs.fat -F 32 command to create FAT 32 format volume in the new partition

I tested your answer and found partition with the ext4 volume labeled "writable" does not appear in gparted. Also /var/log and /var/crash are mounted to different folders this volume.

That indicates that I remember wrong... Idea added above.

Your updated answer works with Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.1. I was able to add a 4th partition with a FAT32 formatted volume to the three already existing partitions in the GPT. I used the fdisk --wipe never command to create the 4th partition. This command automatically moved the secondary (backup) partition table and header to the end of the flash drive. I used the mkfs.fat -F 32 command to create FAT 32 format volume in the new partition..

Well, I made an attempt to edit it accordingly; I'd need to play with this "feature" to get the very details correct, based on your comment.

I edited you question in an attempt to state what I found in testing. Also, I would like to clarify the problem with gparted. This image shows the output from fdisk, which does correctly list all three partitions. However, gparted only shows the entire flash drive as iso9660.

This image shows the result after booting from the flash drive, then viewing the flash drive from machine with Linux already installed. You can see the 4th partition was automatically added and is writable. You used Ubuntu and the OP used Mint. One difference between the ISO files is Ubuntu has a GPT and Mint has a legacy MBR partition table.

Someone rejected your edits, I'll take your findings, and add my own to review this as time permits. Apparent is that the idea behind the text works.

Ventoy is a tool that will create a bootable USB device containing a partition with the HPFS/NTFS/exFAT type, where you can copy-paste .iso files. Then when booting from Ventoy, it will display the list of available ISOs. But you can also store any file on this partition.
You can also reserve space to create an EXT4 partition if you prefer.

This is what is currently posted to your question:

Let's say I downloaded a bootable ISO of some Linux distribution, because I want to install Linux later. I can burn that ISO onto my USB flash drive. However the device will keep the iso9660 filesystem, so it won't be writable. I can install Linux, but I cannot do anything else with my USB flash drive.

I am not sure exactly was meant by “burn”. This answer defines “burn” to mean copying the ISO file to a flash drive through the use of the dd command. This command is available from Linux, macOS and Windows.
You posted in a comment that the ISO, used in your answer, was for Linux Mint. I downloaded and burned the Cinnamon Edition of Linux Mint 22 LTS to an USB flash drive. The command I used is given below. I entered the command while booted to the current Debian release of peppermintOS.
sudo dd if=~/Downloads/linuxmint-22-cinamon-64bit.iso bs=1M status=progress of=/dev/sdb

The resultant flash drive is both BIOS and UEFI bootable. Regardless of how you boot the flash drive, a partition, with a writable Ext4 volume, is automatically created in the free space at the end of this drive.
Your post currently asks the following question:

So, is it possible convert the ISO into a "normal" ext4 filesystem, and still keep the USB stick bootable?

Converting is not necessary to solve the problem described in your post. You can solve your problem by booting the flash drive to Mint and then shutting down.

For others reading this answer, you may have a Linux ISO file which does not automatically create a new partition, when “burned” to a USB flash drive and then booted. There is also the possibility that a user would want new partition with a format other than ext4. In these cases, I would refer you to the answer posted by Hannu.

"a partition, with a writable Ext4 volume, is automatically created in the free space at the end of this drive." -> really? I don't think so, maybe did you create it later?

Everything I am posting has been tested. When you first boot the flash drive, Mint creates a new writeable ext4 formatted partition and uses the partition to write log files. You can write files to this partition while booted from this flash drive or afterwards when not booted from the flash drive.
